# Segmentation fault when copy Qt5Core.dll and plugins from mingw32 folder to local directory where exe file exists

Tags: windows-10, qt5, mingw32

Windows 10, mingw32 (C:\msys64\mingw32\bin), qtcreator(installed by pacman).
My program (HelloAnim.exe) is qt quick GUI, I build a release version and it works with build folder:

```
 "D:\qt\build-HelloAnim-Desktop_Qt_5_15_5_shared_MinGW_w64_MINGW32_MSYS2-Release\release"
```

However when I copy Qt5Core.dll from mingw32 folder to the exe folder, and run HelloAnim.exe, the error pops up like:

```
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Then I copy the folder "plugins" from C:\msys64\mingw32\share\qt5 to the exe folder and run, still the same error.

Then I edit a qt.conf file placed into the exe folder with below content:

```
[Paths]
Plugins=D:/qt/build-HelloAnim-Desktop_Qt_5_15_5_shared_MinGW_w64_MINGW32_MSYS2-Release/release/plugins
```

Then run HelloAnim.exe, then segmentation fault error appears like below:

```
# ./HelloAnim.exe
Debug: arguments=======  ("D:\\qt\\build-HelloAnim-Desktop_Qt_5_15_5_shared_MinGW_w64_MINGW32_MSYS2-Release\\release\\HelloAnim.exe")
Debug: current dir:  "D:/qt/build-HelloAnim-Desktop_Qt_5_15_5_shared_MinGW_w64_MINGW32_MSYS2-Release/release"
Warning: Attribute Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
Debug: touch devices:  ()
Warning: QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:3:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:3:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:3:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
Warning: qrc:/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
Segmentation fault
```

Don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a lot of details so it's hard to guess, what you have deployed and what is missing.
But your installation folder should contain your exe and Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Network.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll (whatever your application needs). Then there should also be the files that come with the compiler (libwinpthread-1.dll, libEGL.dll, libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libGLESv2.dll). Again depending on your app: opengl32sw.dll.

Then there should be a couple of folders:
audio bearer iconengines imageformats mediaservice

Most important: platforms

Inside platforms: qwindows.dll

But instead of maintaining all this manually, it is easier to let Qt do the job. There is a tool call windeployqt.exe (in Qt's mingw/bin folder) and this will do the job for you. And most of the times, it will not miss any files.

Comment: windeployqt.exe ./HelloAnim.exe, not working, still segmentation fault. Actually I tried to copy all files in C:\msys64\mingw32\bin and HelloAnim.exe to another folder (e.g. in D:\temp), still segmentation fault. My application is 32 bit, the Windows 10 is 64 bit.

Comment: finally get it work, add --qmldir to windeployqt.exe for qtquick project.